# Multiply each element of an array to each other

Tags: perl

I have an array of float numbers: (.25, .45, .15, .27). I would like to multiply each element with each other than divide by the number of array elements.

```
foreach my $element (@array)
{
my $score = $score * $element;
}
$score = $score/$numofelements;
```

This produces the value 0. Not sure if my syntax is correct.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: I just now thought I'd point out that unless you declared `$score` elsewhere, the scope in which you have it now will not work.  This is why it's zero.

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is correct, but you are initializing the `$score` variable each time through the loop, which sets it to 0 each iteration.  Simply move it outside the loop and it should work:

```
my $score = 1 #Need to initialize to 1 for multiplying
foreach my $element (@array) {
    $score *= $element;
}
$score = $score/$numofelements; #Assuming $numofelements is set already
```

Answer (score 6):

There is also the [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) route.

```
use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @array = (.25, .45, .15, .27);
my $mult = reduce { $a * $b } 1, @array;
my $score = $mult / @array;
```

If you run into the warning about `$a` and `$b`, [**here**](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1021888) is a thread on Perl monks about how to silence them.

Comment: @RayToal I figured it was important.  Running it myself I stumbled into some warnings.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but a little more Perl-ish perhaps:

```
my @array = (3, 5, 4, 7);

my $score = 1;
$score *= $_ for @array;
print ($score / @array), "\n";
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/p5PWYd)

Note that it is probably best not to use `$numelements` because there is no guarantee that value stores the length of the array.  Just use `@array` in a scalar context and you get the length of the array for free.